# Android ICS 4.0 OS

Tags: android

I am a new Android developer starting out.

I hope that someone from the androids developers team can answer this question: if I have a tablet with android ICS 4.0 OS, given that this OS is UNIX-based, can I install the Android Developer Kit and related platform+ packages on it, so that I might study development on the go whilst traveling with my tablet?

I understand that one of the requisite OSes for the android development kit is UNIX - GNU C Library (`glibc`) 2.7 or later. Is ICS 4.0 compatible with this?

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in the [AIDE project](https://plus.google.com/101304250883271700981/about), you can download their application [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui).

> Develop Android Apps on Android with AIDE - the Android Java IDE AIDE
>   is an integrated development environment (IDE) for developing real
>   Android Apps directly on Android devices. AIDE supports the full
>   edit-compile-run cycle: write code with the feature rich editor
>   offering advanced features like code completion, real-time error
>   checking, refactoring and smart code navigation, and run your App with
>   a single click. AIDE will turn your Android tablet with keyboard into
>   a real development box. We use the Transformer Prime running Ice Cream
>   Sandwich to code with AIDE. AIDE will turn your Android Phone into a
>   small development computer to browse and touch your code on the go.
>   AIDE is fully compatible with Eclipse projects. You can just copy the
>   sourcecode to your device and open the Eclipse project in AIDE to
>   start coding. Alternatively you can keep your sourcecode on your
>   Dropbox - AIDE integrates with Dropbox and allows to easily download
>   from your Dropbox and sync back your changes. AIDE supports GIT for
>   professional development

Answer (score 2):

> can i install the android developer kit and related platform+ packages on it so i can study development on the go whilst traveling with my tablet?

Not exactly. [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en) offers on-device development of apps, but I think you need to let it install the tools.

> I understand that one of the requisite OS for the android development kit is unix - GNU C Library (glibc) 2.7 or later

That would only be required if you are either building the firmware or building native code with the NDK, neither of which is supported on the device itself.